# Is it better to learn basic php and work in real time project or learn core php?

Tags: php

One of my freelancer friend work with wordpress, he knows basic php, but does not working in core php program. During his work he take sample code from Google and then edit that code and use on his client project. It always works and he says he could understand most of the language. Because he works in basic level of c,c++,java,html,css,php. His motto is -- work and learn though it takes much time.
On the other hand, another my friend learn php from very basic and want to be a core programmer. His motto is -- first learn then work with less time.

I am just confused what can i do. If everything is possible from Google after learning basic php then why i learn php very deeply. Is it good to code myself whether all type of code is available on internet?

Comment: i have the same problem. I can't wait for a good answer

Comment: what is mean he does know basic php and does not know core php ..? i think core php is the basic php it might possible that one not familiar with oo in  php or mvc architecture

Comment: the faster approach is first learn some than start a project (not commercial just for practice ) make sure you cover all security concern (leave performance for a while),database,login,file uploading,...it will make you smooth in php ...

Comment: The trick to learning is to take the time to learn. Mindlessly tweaking someone else's code won't help, but reading, working with, and paying attention to well written code can be enormously beneficial.  If you take the time to try to understand how things work and why the way they are, then this will uncover gaps in your core knowledge that you can then fill.  Alternately core knowledge needs to be reinforced by use and there are practical concerns that aren't expressed in theory.  Which route you take isn't as important as the amount of time spent fully digesting concepts and approaches.

Comment: @MattWhipple yup ...matt using other code ..is ridiculously bad  (not talking about  framework ) ..its have 80:20 time ratio .... 80% take time if we use oher code ..since first we need to understand code ..than find bug and remove extra  part ... and if we write own it just take 20% time

Comment: You need to at least learn the fundamentals of PHP there are plenty of tutorials on the internet covering just about every topic. I would suggest starting with that and building small applications trying to write all of the code yourself and not being a script kiddie! 

> “Any fool can know. The point is to understand.” ― Albert Einstein

Comment: @NullPointer Part of code being well written is that it should have clear intent and be either well commented or self documenting. When starting out you can easily churn out poor code more quickly that degrades into an unmaintainable, idiosyncratic mess.  If you want to make the journey towards being able to contribute to a larger project with a team, then acquiring best practices and absorbing other's techniques is essential for collaboration.  But well written code is the key phrase here.

Comment: @MattWhipple i do know ...i am just taking for learners not for employ ..who are experienced ...i do know in project time does matter

Answer (score 5):

I think that skill level is tied to compensation. The better skills you have, the more valuable you are. A lot more people can take some PHP code off the Internet, changed it up and make something work. However, a lot fewer people can build architecturally sound and solid software solution to some problem.

It all depends on what you want, if you want to be a top notch software developer, then you should have an attitude of one and try to improve all the time. If you want to get buy and make some money tweaking WordPress sites,  fine. A lot of people do fine with that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what kind of answer you are expecting, but I can tell you this:

I have been working for more than 10 years as a programmer, and I am STILL learning every day with every new project, and even though google is a great help and the kind of info you get there is just incredible, it still doesn't replace your own knowledge and programming skills. Every example you can find on google will still need tweaking and that is where you will NEED to know what you are doing.

I think the point is this: If you are going to work making small websites, charging $10 / hour and just doing basic contact, signup and data forms, then forget about learning php deeply, your friend is right to learn as he goes. And in this case, you should dedicate your time to learn other very important skills like databases, SEO, mobile compatibility, etc, those will give you a greater opportunity to get more customers and projects.

However, if you intend to become a serious programmer and work in large projects, charging 3 or 4 times that amount, then forget about small websites and learn deep programming logic that you can apply in any kind of language or situation.

In the end, there is not right or wrong path, it just depends of your own goals and needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Drupal a lot right now for large e-commerce websites that connect to in-store POS systems. There is no way I would be able to just take code from Google to create these websites. Sure, I can "borrow" simple snippets from documentation; however, on a professional project... this doesn't get you far.

If you want to create an unsecured website, waste 90% of your time on simple bugs that someone with basic knowledge could fix instantly... then sure go the lazy route.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your objective. If your objective is to "learn PHP", then you should definitely learn how to use the language, etc. that way you can make things on your own, rather than having to google things on how to do it.

Googling for solutions is okay as well, however, if you don't know how the code runs, or understand how it works, you won't be able to change it on your own to make it work with what you are trying to do. That is the benefit of understanding the language; you can take existing code, and modify it to make it better or work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To apply correct solutions you need to understand how they work, and what are limits for the particular solution, be able to adopt such solution to the problem. It is like if you would build from cubes - when you are child, you need only basic gravitation rules, but if you want to build really big tower from same cubes you need know more physics and maths,  and possible, to choose another construction units.